# How to Encrypt and UnEncrypt text in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if I could encrypt a raw data so for example:

```
message = encrypt(raw_input("what is your message")) <---- I want this encrypted
```

Then in my server code, I want it unencrypted:

```
print unencrypt(str(message)) <----- I want this
```

I want it similar to this. How can I do it on Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Code:

```
import base64
def encode(key, clear):
    enc = []
    for i in range(len(clear)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc_c = chr((ord(clear[i]) + ord(key_c)) % 256)
        enc.append(enc_c)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc))

def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec_c = chr((256 + ord(enc[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256)
        dec.append(dec_c)
    return "".join(dec)

encoded_string=encode('password','text text')
print encoded_string
decoded_string=decode('password',encoded_string)
print decoded_string
```